# Drag picture but drop name element from a draggable image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While building a drag and drop page, I wish to drag an image to a drop zone but on drop I wish for some HTML to be dropped instead of the image.

Is this possible?

Maybe using the HTML5 as the id text or a file URL.

This is my code:

**Draggable element**

```
 <img id="drag1" name="<h1>My Super Image</h1>" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

**Drop zone**

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

**My header script**

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

I can drag the image to the drop zone, however I would like to drop text instead of the image from the name field. How can I do that?

Comment: not much really, i haven't been able to find any examples/tutorials i can drag and drop the same content but this isnt what im looking for.

Comment: i have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is in the question itself. You just need to change one line of code:

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

That line is telling the browser to append the element with the id specified in `data` (the id of the draggable picture) into the drop element. Modify it so it appends the code in the `name` attribute of the element instead of the whole element.

Something like this:

```
ev.target.innerHTML += document.getElementById(data).name;
```

Once you do that, instead of appending the image, you will be appending whatever is in the `name` attribute of the draggable image.

You can see it working here:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.target.innerHTML += document.getElementById(data).name;
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    border:1px dotted gray;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="drag1" name="<h1>My Super Image</h1>" src="http://lorempixel.com/336/69/people" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"/>
```